# QGIS 2.16 - Missing menu Vector > Research Tools > Vector Grid

Tags: qgis

I just upgraded to QGIS 2.16 on Xubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.4 and I'm missing the "Research Tools" under the Vector menu. I'm specifically looking for the Vector Grid option.

I didn't notice any error messages during the startup, or the error logs. Would anyone know how to resolve this?